# How can I select only the content of a @media in CSS with regexp in Emacs?

Tags: regular-expressions

I am trying to select the content of @media in CSS with regexp in Emacs (elisp) to make a slight change in the color of the background or font, so I can easily see that I am editing inside of them.

I already came up with this regexp:

```
@media.*\{\\(.*[^]]*?\}\\)[ \t\n]*\}
```

And this is selecting the content most of the times, but I'm having a problem when I have comments or leading spaces after the last bracket before the closing bracket of the @media statement.

I want to match just the content inside every @media query brackets.

```
/*... css above*/
/*tablet*/
@media (max-width: 800px){
    ._desktop-only {display:none !important;}
    ._tablet-only {display:initial;}
    ._mobile-only {display:none;}
}
/*mobile*/
@media (max-width: 480px){
     ._desktop-only {display:none;}
     ._tablet-only {display:none !important;}
     ._mobile-only {display:initial;} /* comment */
}
/*more css below...*/
```

Some people might suggest that I should create separated files. I usually do that, but sometimes I have to edit the files as they are. And don't mind much the sample, because my goal is to edit large CSS files with a lot of statements inside of them, and I want to be able to see if I am editing the main statements or the variation of them.

Comment: Please do not post the same question to this site and to StackOverflow. Choose one site only.

Comment: I just found out about this site. I meant to delete from the other site, but I've got busy.

Comment: No problem. And thanks for considering it.

Comment: Maybe show some examples of the CSS that you want to match, to give a better idea?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704728/emacs-is-it-possible-to-match-strings-with-balanced-parens-with-emacs-regex/9173713#9173713

Answer (score 2):

Since [regular expressions can't match balanced expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_the_lemma), your regex needs some additional hints to find the final `}`. E.g. if the first `}` at the start of a line necessarily must be the one belonging to the initial `{` (and all inner ones are indented), then

```
@media.*\{\\(\\(\n\\|.\\)*?\n\\)}
```

seems to do the job (for your example at least).

---

That said, I would just use narrowing – first I ensure point is in the `@media`'s curly braces, then I hit shift-F11 which I have bound to this "narrow-DWIM" thing which I have no idea where I got from

```
(global-set-key
 (kbd "<S-f11>")
 (defun narrow-or-widen-dwim (p)
   "If the buffer is narrowed, it widens. Otherwise, it narrows intelligently.
Intelligently means: region, org-src-block, org-subtree, or defun,
whichever applies first.
Narrowing to org-src-block actually calls `org-edit-src-code'.

With prefix P, don't widen, just narrow even if buffer is already
narrowed."
   (interactive "P")
   (declare (interactive-only))
   (cond ((and (buffer-narrowed-p) (not p)) (widen))
         ((region-active-p)
          (narrow-to-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
         ((derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
          ;; `org-edit-src-code' is not a real narrowing command.
          ;; Remove this first conditional if you don't want it.
          (cond ((org-in-src-block-p)
                 (org-edit-src-code)
                 (delete-other-windows))
                ((org-at-block-p)
                 (org-narrow-to-block))
                (t (org-narrow-to-subtree))))
         (t (narrow-to-defun)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the [cexp](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/cexp) extension of Emacs' regular expressions that also matches balanced expressions.

With that library you can use the following elisp expression:

`(cexp-search-forward "@media *\\!(.*\\!) *\\!(.*\\!)")`

which works just like `re-search-forward` with additional sexps.

If you run that elisp expression match data is set as follows:

- `(match-string 0)`: the overall match

  ```
  "@media (max-width: 480px){
    ._desktop-only {display:none;}
    ._tablet-only {display:none !important;}
    ._mobile-only {display:initial;} /* comment */
  }"
  ```
- `(match-string 1)`: the stuff before the first sexp `"@media "`
- `(match-string 2)`: the first sexp `"(max-width: 800px)"`
- `(match-string 3)`: the regular expression match within the first balanced expression, i.e. the match for `.*` within the match for the first `\\!(.*\\!)`: `"(max-width: 800px)"`
- `(match-string 4)`: the stuff between the first and the second sexp `""`
- `(match-string 5)`: the second balanced expression

  ```
  "{
   ._desktop-only {display:none !important;}
   ._tablet-only {display:initial;}
   ._mobile-only {display:none;}
  }"
  ```
- `(match-string 6)`: the (first) match for `.*` within the second balanced expression, i.e., `"{"`

Match string 6 is right and perhaps interesting. It shows the difference between the sub-match that matches a balanced expression (i.e. match string 5) and the match within the balanced expression (i.e. match string 6). The dot `.` only matches characters that are not new-lines and on the first line of the second balanced expression there is only the opening curly brace.

You can even use

`(cexp-search-forward "@media *\\!(\\!) *\\!(\\!)")`

In that case you get empty strings as `(match-string 3)` and `(match-string 6)`. Even so you find the balanced expressions as `(match-string 2)` and `(match-string 5)`.

For a better understanding I cite here the doc-string of `cexp-search-forward`:

> Search for combined regular and balanced expressions (cexp).
>   The syntax of cexp is almost that of a regular expression with the exception that the string !( introduces a balanced expression and !) closes a balanced expression. The matched balanced expressions and the matches for the regular expressions before, in between, and after the sexps appear in the match data.
>   Regular expression braces ( and ) may not include balanced expressions (sexps).
>   On the other hand balanced expressions may include regular expressions with groups.