# emacs regex to match balanced parenthesis

Tags: regular-expressions, balanced-parentheses, parentheses

How can emacs lisp match balanced parenthesis? for example: "foo(bar(),hee()) out()" should be match "foo(bar(),hee())".

I try below statement but it doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env emacs --script

(setq str "foo(bar(),hee()) out()")
(when (string-match "foo(.*?)" str)
  (print (match-string 0 str))
)
```

Currently, the output is:

```
"foo(bar()"
```

But my expected output is:

```
foo(bar(),hee())
```

Comment: A similar question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30432/how-can-i-select-only-the-content-of-a-media-in-css-with-regexp-in-emacs/42185#42185 My answer there is [cexp](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/cexp).

Comment: Not a direct answer, but whatever your use case is, you're likely going to have a much better time using `syntax-ppss` if you want to find balanced parens.

Comment: @beetlej Note that regular expressions *cannot* do what you are asking.  You would instead use something like `forward-sexp` to move over a balanced expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phils already pointed out in [his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45387/emacs-regex-to-match-balanced-parenthesis#comment69764_45387) `forward-sexp` is the function that parses balanced expressions.

You could modify your example as follows to match the balanced expression with vanilla emacs:

```el
#!/usr/bin/env emacs --script
(setq str "foo(bar(),hee()) out()")
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert str)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let (end)
    (when (and (search-forward "foo(" nil t)
           (condition-case err
           (setq end (scan-sexps (1- (point)) 1))
         (scan-error nil)))
      (print (buffer-substring (match-beginning 0) end))
      )))
```

I already pointed out [in my comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45387/emacs-regex-to-match-balanced-parenthesis/45389#comment69762_45387) that I would use [cexp](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/cexp/blob/master/cexp.el).
In that case the modified code would be:

```el
#!/usr/bin/env emacs --script
(setq str "foo(bar(),hee()) out()")
(require 'cexp)
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert str)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (when (cexp-search-forward "foo\\!(\\`(\\!)" nil t)
    (print (match-string 0))))
```

The parts of the combined expression `` "foo\\!(\\`(\\!)" ``:

- `foo` matches itself
- `\!(...\!)` matches a balanced expression
- `` \`... `` at the very beginning of the balanced expression...
- `(` should be a parenthesis

Comment: The cexp version works fine in emacs editor, but when run it as script, I got below error "Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, cexp". can I use require statement in script?

Comment: @beetlej Emacs does not load any initialization file with `--script` option. So **no** `load-path` modifications from your init files are executed. Either you save `cexp.el` into one of the directories in the compiled-in `load-path`, or you set the load path in your [`site-start.el` file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), or you replace the `(require 'cexp)` with `(load-library "/absolute/path/to/cexp.el")`.